# Multiple domains for login with google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

We are adding login in with google to an ecom website which powers multiple domains/locales where we have a different domain for each store.

The problem is we have different privacy policies for each country. How do we manage this in a single app- or does each domain require its own application

Comment: I am not 100% sure - if you have different privacy policy URLs then you will need separate OAuth clients, one per region/policy. Have you considered one privacy policy page with sections for each supported region?

Comment: @JohnHanley We could do this but will we still need to add call back urls for each individiual domain?

Comment: I don't know the best answer. Are we talking three domains or 500? As a customer, I would expect the privacy page to match the store's domain.